# How to reserve certain amount of memory and using segment register to access?

Tags: x86, memory, protection

So basically I am trying to re-implement a memory protection technique, with the description like this:

- A 256M segment is reserved for application code and
- A 512M segment is reserved for some special data (can't be modified during runtime)
- ...
- `%fs` register is used to access the 512M memory of special data.

I am thinking to leverage some segmentation based protection on 32bit x86, however, I am trapped in the first step, **how to reserve some memory for the special data mentioned above ?**

So basically what i am trying to do is very similar with Google's Native Client, I 
quote some thing for its [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Native_Client).

> The x86-32 implementation of Native Client is notable for its novel 
>       sandboxing method which makes use of the x86 architecture's rarely 
>       used segmentation facility.
>
> Native Client sets up x86 segments to restrict the memory range 
>       that the sandboxed code can access.

Could anyone give me some help on this issue ?

Comment: In Virtual Memory Operating Systems memory protection is implemented by the OS, which application code has no control over. Unless you are writing some emulator or a virtual machine you cannot guarantee that memory will always be available at some specific address.  Even the `VirtualAlloc` will not reserve memory at any adress.

Comment: @ExtremeCoders, I modified the question, I made something wrong before. anyway, there should be some methods, thinking of Google's [NaCI](https://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/) [paper](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en/us/pubs/archive/34913.pdf)

Comment: Google's NaCl implementation is complex and uses many techniques. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026794/x86-segmentation-in-user-mode) related qs on SO. [This](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-12/Briefings/Rohlf/BH_US_12_Rohlf_Google_Native_Client_Slides.pdf) pdf analyzes the NaCl architecture.

Comment: There are certain limitations, but you should have a look at the Windows API, and specifically functions such as VirtualProtect(). Some methods for virtual memory management are also used for anti-debugging purposes, e.g. using VirtualProtect() and ZeroMemory() an application may strip its PE header.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for Linux then take a look at http://linux.die.net/man/2/arch_prctl, specifically at the `ARCH_SET_FS` option.